# Pandas Merge SingleIndex to MultiIndex from CSV

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, merge, multi-index

Given the following tables from CSV files:

CSV 1:

```
    A   B                C
    AA  BB1     BB2     CC
0   1   text    5       7
1   2   text2   6       8
2   3   text3   7       9
```

in Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
mi=pd.read_csv('csv_to_mi.csv',header=[0,1],encoding='latin-1')
mi = mi.rename(columns={'Unnamed: 2_level_0':'B'})
mi

    A   B               C
    AA  BB1      BB2    CC  
0   1   text     5      7
1   2   text2    6      8
2   3   text3    7      9
```

CSV 2:

```
    A       D   E
    text    T1  9
    text2   T2  10
    text3   T3  11
```

in Pandas:

```
si=pd.read_csv('csv_to_si.csv',encoding='latin-1')
si

    A       D   E
0   text    T1  9
1   text2   T2  10
2   text3   T3  11
```

I want to merge them on m1['B','BB1'] and s1['A'] to get this (or a functional multi-indexed data frame):

```
    A   B               C   D   E
    AA  BB1      BB2    CC  
0   1   text     5      7   T1   9
1   2   text2    6      8   T2   10
2   3   text3    7      9   T3   11
```

I did something similar before, and it seemed to work out okay, except when I tried to rename 2 columns on the merge data frame and it dropped all other (non-renamed) columns for some reason. I have also tried reading the multi-indexed csv with just the top header row (as single-indexed), merging the two together, and then making the result multi-indexed. That seemed to work until I ran into the renaming issue.

I tried to convert the single-indexed data frame into a multi-indexed data frame first, [per jezrael's sage advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37364859/pandas-add-header-row-for-multiindex/37364923#37364923) (which worked well), then merge with multi-indexed one, but that didn't work either.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Under first level columns  `D` and `E` can be `CC` and `CC`?

Comment: Unfortunately no. But they can be anything else (even numbers, as per your previous solution linked in this post).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) with [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) column `('A', 0)`:

```
cols = list(zip(si.columns, range(si.shape[1])))
si.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(cols)
print (si)
       A   D   E
       0   1   2
0   text  T1   9
1  text2  T2  10
2  text3  T3  11

print (pd.merge(mi,si, left_on=[('B','BB1')], right_on=[('A', 0)]).drop([('A', 0)], axis=1))
   A      B      C   D   E
  AA    BB1 BB2 CC   1   2
0  1   text   5  7  T1   9
1  2  text2   6  8  T2  10
2  3  text3   7  9  T3  11
```

EDIT by comment - use [`get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html):

```
print (df)
   A      B      C   D   E
  AA    BB1 BB2 CC   1   2
0  1   text   5  7  T1   9
1  2  text2   6  8  T2  10
2  3  text3   7  9  T3  11

print (df.columns.get_level_values(0))
Index(['A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], dtype='object')

cols = list(zip(df.columns.get_level_values(0), df.columns.get_level_values(0)))
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(cols)
print (df)
   A      B     C   D   E
   A      B  B  C   D   E
0  1   text  5  7  T1   9
1  2  text2  6  8  T2  10
2  3  text3  7  9  T3  11
```

EDIT1: If you need merge on multiple columns:

```
print (mi)
   A      B      C
  AA    BB1 BB2 CC
0  1   text   5  7
1  2  text2   6  8
2  3  text3   7  9

cols = list(zip(si.columns, range(si.shape[1])))
si.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(cols)
print (si)
       A   D  E
       0   1  2
0   text  T1  1
1  text2  T2  2
2  text3  T3  3

df = (pd.merge(mi,si, left_on=[('B','BB1'),('A','AA')], right_on=[('A', 0), ('E', 2)])
        .drop([('A', 0), ('E', 2)], axis=1))

print (df)
   A      B      C   D
  AA    BB1 BB2 CC   1
0  1   text   5  7  T1
1  2  text2   6  8  T2
2  3  text3   7  9  T3
```

Comment: Thanks! By the way, what if I wanted the bottom set of columns in si to be the same as the top (i.e. level 0 = 'A', 'D', 'E'  and level 1 = 'A', 'D', 'E' ), in a way that copies the top header?

Comment: Great! One more thing; what if I need to join on more than one column? I tried right_on=[(col1,col1),(col2,col2)] but no luck.

Comment: Sorry, typo on my end.

Comment: No problem. ;) Good luck! And thank you for all accepting.